# Facebook app on both iOS and Android doesn't work on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, android, iphone, facebook

I have an Asus RT66AC-router at home. I also have two iOS-devices (iPhone SE and iPad Mini 3, both with iOS 10) and two Android phones (HTC M9+ and an Xperia, both with Android 6).

When using the Facebook app on any of these phones, after a few minutes the app loses the connection. The workaround is to disable/reenable WiFi. After that it works for a few minutes again. The problem is perfectly easy to reproduce. I have never this problem when using the mobile network on any of these devices, nor do any of my two computers (Macs) have problems with their network connection. Not even other apps on the affected devices have similar problems. The router itself works fine and I restart it maybe 1-2 times/year, but that is mostly because my ISP has some intermittent problem.

What is going on here? It has been like this with dozens of versions of the Facebook app for at least a year, probably longer. Does the Facebook app on both iOS and Android use some special network stack that is incompatible with Asus routers? I haven't noticed this problem at other locations but, on the other hand, I rarely use Facebook for such long sessions at work or other "not-at-home" locations.